# Creative way to get accurate temperature without $$$?

Tags: measurements, temperature

I am looking for a way to measure temperature to about +/-1F (or at least +/-1C) accurate around room temperatures (50F-80F).

Currently I am comparing three different thermometers and the result is beyond frustrating:

[image]

1. The Carrier heat pump thermostat might be the least accurate and has not even accuracy specified
2. The Acurite is supposed to be [accurate to +/-1F](https://www.acurite.com/shop-all/weather-instruments/weather-sensors-and-parts/sensors/replacement-sensor-609txc.html).
3. The Kestrel Drop D1 is supposed to be [accurate to +/-0.9F](https://kestrelinstruments.com/kestrel-drop-d1-temperature-logger).

At least one is lying and pretty far off because they can't be more than 1.9F apart. But from my measurements there is up to 4.5F difference!

Is there a good way to verify which one is correct and use it to calibrate the others, without spending thousands of dollars in proper temperature normal/calibration equipment?

It seems the temperature probes of multimeters are even less accurate.

I also got an infrared thermometer ([this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08TT5J6TY)). It states an accuracy up to +/-2.7F which is also pretty high. The description mentions a calibration using ice bath but I am concerned that these thermometers do not just have an offset but gain error/nonlinearity as well.

Lastly I am thinking of getting a thermal camera ([like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BLJ3XJ3Z)). While these have accuracies of 50mK, this is just relative accuracy, not absolute. Absolute seems pretty poor too.

Comment: RTD probes (and readers) should get you to 0.2C without too much money, something on the order of $100 (and probably a lot less on AliExpress). You can also get two temperature reference points for free: freezing water, and boiling water (remember to adjust for altitude/pressure)

Comment: also consider, for something like a thermostat in a room, that there will be a bunch of variation just from height above the floor, or difference of one wall to another wall due to internal airflows. So better than +/-1C probably not necessary. And for that, any of today's common digital chip based sensors should be more than adequate.

Comment: @PeteW of course I mounted all three thermometers on the same spot. Variations should be minimal.

Answer (score 1):

I used thermocouples, but to get and keep accuracy it all needs calibrating - the thermocouples, any extensions and the meter.

In my situation we even calibrated the 30 way switching box...

So a thermocouple, checked and calibrated will be accurate but you need to pay - what you consider cheap depends if you really want accuracy.

Comment: We're in the age of AliExpress ... everything is affordable now

Comment: @PeteW yes, but will it last 5 weeks or 5 years?

Comment: Can you share details how to calibrate? And what thing I’d need from AliExpress? Right now, I feel I’d just add another unknown the the set of thermometers …

Comment: I’ve got one more idea: How about digital fever thermometers? Given that they need to be accurate in a fairly narrow range, I’d expect them to be accurate around 38C/100F.